# Can't set correct auth cookie by using addCookie in Gatling

Tags: java, performance-testing, gatling

I am trying to move my Login to application outside of my performance tests made in Gatling.

Login authentication is by stored Cookie, so I want to log in to app and obtain an auth cookie in another Class, and then parse it directly into "addCookie" method in gatling (so i guess it should be stored in session of next gatling performance tests)

I have method getAuthCookie in class CookieSaver

```
public String getAuthCookie() throws Exception {

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    prop.load(new FileInputStream("data.properties"));
    String user = prop.getProperty("username");
    String pass = prop.getProperty("password");
    String url = prop.getProperty("url");

    Map<Object, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("username", user);
    data.put("password", pass);

    HttpRequest request2 = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .POST(buildFormDataFromMap(data))
            .uri(URI.create(url))
            .setHeader("User-Agent", "Java 11 HttpClient Bot")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request2, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    String cookie = String.valueOf(response.headers().firstValue("set-cookie"));

    System.out.println(response.statusCode());

    System.out.println(response.body());
    String fixedCookie = cookie.replace("Optional", "");
    return fixedCookie;
}
```

and I am trying to use it in .exec(addCookie........

```
ChainBuilder search;

{

    try {
        search = exec(flushCookieJar())
                .exec(flushHttpCache())

                .exec(addCookie(Cookie("set-cookie", authCookie.getAuthCookie()).withDomain("localhost")))
                
                .pause(1)

                .exec(
                        http("Contacts")
                                .get("/transactions/contacts")
                                .check(
                                        status().is(200).saveAs("Response")
                                ))
                .exec(session -> {
                    System.out.println("session1: " +session);
                    return session;
                })

                .exec(flushSessionCookies())


                .pause(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

I obtain the Cookie and set it correctly into session (verified in logs after run), but i obtain 401 when trying to run next step of performance tests, which is simple get

I've tried log in to application inside performance tests and it's working correctly, but i would need to move log in outside of performance tests

This works:

```
ChainBuilder search;

{

    try {
        search = exec(http("Home").get("/"))

                .exec(
                        http("Login")
                                .post("/login")
                                .formParam("username", "user")
                                .formParam("password", "pw")
                                .check(
                                        status().is(200)
                                )
                )
                .pause(1)

                .exec(
                        http("Contacts")
                                .get("/transactions/contacts")
                                .check(
                                        status().is(200).saveAs("Response")
                                ))
                .exec(session -> {
                    System.out.println("sesja1: " +session);
                    return session;
                })

                .exec(flushSessionCookies())


                .pause(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you're sending cookies they need to go in [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header, [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) is what **server** uses for creating the cookies
2. I don't think you really "moving" your login "out of" your performance tests, you're just using your custom code which will still be present in metrics and impacting response time and throughput (and leaving the connection to the server open by the way), maybe it worth simulating logins somewhere in [before hook](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/simulation/#hooks) and use a [feeder](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/feeder/) when the real simulation starts
3. Having load generator and the system under test running on the same machine is not the best idea as they both will be [struggling for the operating system resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and even a comprehensive [APM tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apm-tools-comparison) won't be able to tell you where the bottleneck is

Comment: Thanks for 2. and 3. tips
Could you please give more details about 1.?
I mean what is an example to pass the Cookie into Cookie header.
While using 
'.exec(addCookie(Cookie("set-cookie", authCookie.getAuthCookie()).withDomain("localhost")))' 
I entering my Cookie name (set-cookie) - where can i set it to Header?